# Excluding some 3rd party jar in ear using maven

Tags: maven, ear

I am building an ear using maven `<packaging>ear</packaging>` tag.
One of the declared dependencies is adding it's transitive dependency to the generated ear. Is there any way to exclude this in the generated ear?

That is, my EAR pom has a dependency on module_A, this somewhere along the tree has a dependency on module_X which is getting packaged in the generated ear.

Is there any way not to include this(module_X) in the ear?

Directly adding an `excludes` tag for module_X in my pom did not work.

Comment: If the dependency declared in a parent POM is not used by all its children, you should probably reconsider whether it should be declared in that parent. Or is it indeed a dependency, but you just don't want it packaged inside the EAR because it's provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is possible with maven. You just have to simly add a tag exclusions in the pom of your ear, something like that :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>my.group</groupId>
   <artifactId>module_A</artifactId>
   <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
         <groupId>my.group</groupId>
         <artifactId>module_X</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This tag works, I use it in many ear projects. Maybe it's because an other artifact, which is also packaged in module_A, needs module_X to compile and so you also have to exclude it in his dependency.

Comment: It works, I had made a mistake specifying the artifactId of the module to be excluded.(Used xx_1.0.1 instead of xx_1.0.2).

Answer (score 0):

If the dependency is scoped  as `compile` in the parent POM and you need it to be `provided` within your EAR, you can use dependency management within the child POM where you need to change its scope:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.group</groupId>
            <artifactId>transitive-dependency</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```